# which is the best mysql connection method to use stored procedure in php?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, connection

There are three  methods to connect to mysql from php. mysql_connect,mysqli,PDO.
Which is best one to use a stored procedure in my application?

Please guide me

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli` is straightforwardly better than `mysql`. PDO has a lot of good things going for it. I have a codebase in which at the moment I use `mysqli` along with stored procedures, and I don't have any complaints.

Answer (score 0):

PDO supports stored procedure calls. Good tutorial here
http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Answer (score 0):

PHP PDO is the easiest way to go, it takes care of all the specifics.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

example:

```
$pdo = new PDO( <connection_data> );
$stat = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?');

$ids = array(1,2,3);
foreach($ids as $id) {
  $r = $stat->execute(array($id));
  if($r===false) # something wrong
  else while(($c = $stat->fetch())!==false) {
    var_dump($c);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use pdo because it supports not only mysql but also several other databases like MSSQL, Oracle, IBM DB2, PostgreSQL etc. Here is a great tutorial on [PDO](http://a2znotes.blogspot.in/2014/09/introduction-to-pdo.html).